# Insufficient RAM to run QGIS - yet I have 32GB available

Tags: qgis

I have a question about running QGIS 3.8 Zanzibar on a MacPro running Sierra OS 10.12. I am hoping to use the app for species distribution mapping and was teaching myself using an online tutorial. However, the app kept failing at the same point saying I required 513 MB to continue. My Mac has 4x 8GB RAM chips installed, all functioning, but there does not seem to be a way to allocate more memory to any particular application.

Does this mean I will be unable to use QGIS or is there a way to get the application to obtain more of the available RAM (32GB). At this point I have done a restart and have very little else memory hungry running, but still the same issue. This is frustrating all my plans for a very large project.

Comment: Please be more specific. What were you doing when this error occured? Have you checked with the bugs reports? Have you considered updating to the latest LTR?

Comment: And a further question - what are the size of the rasters you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking to make sure you have enabled rendering with multiple parallel CPU cores.

Check under **Settings > Options** > **Rendering** and then under  **Rendering Behavior**, make sure **Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores** is checked.

You can also specify a maximum number of cores to use.